# How to avoid circular dependency between two classes?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I have two classes - one defines `BaseActivity` (a global parent for all my activities in the app) and other is an `AsyncTask` class in which I defined common networking operation. But I have next problem. `AsyncTask` class named `RestfulNetworkTasks` in his `onPostExecute()` method must call `UpdateCurrentActivityAfterNetworkOperation()` which is defined in `BaseActivity` class but `BaseActivity` class also have to create an instance of `RestfulNetworkTasks`. Here is code which illustrates this problem clearly.

```
class RestfulNetworkTasks extends AsyncTask<Pair<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>, Void, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> {
    private ImmutableMap<String, Object> serverData_;
    NetworkOperation LowLevelRestOperations_ = new NetworkOperation();

    @Override
    protected LinkedHashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(Pair<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>... params) {
        return LowLevelRestOperations_.executeServerCommand(params[0].getValue0(), params[0].getValue1());
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result) {
        serverData_ = copyOf(result);
        BaseActivity instance_Activity = new BaseActivity(); 
        //BaseActivity injection (It is too bad to create Activity in such a way - I know!) So I need some piece of advice
        instance_Activity.UpdateCurrentActivityAfterNetworkOperation(serverData_);
        //Here I must call method for updating GUI after operation
    }

    public ImmutableMap<String, Object> GetDataFromServer() {
        return serverData_;
    }
}

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    RestfulNetworkTasks serverOperation_ = new RestfulNetworkTasks(); //RestfulNetworkTasks injection

    public void UpdateCurrentActivityAfterNetworkOperation(
        ImmutableMap<String, Object> server_data) {
    }// Here is this method which I will override in my child activities

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ImmutableMap<String, Object> Login(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> parameters) {
        Pair<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> params_ = new Pair<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>(LOGIN_COMMAND, parameters);
        serverOperation_.execute(params_);
        return serverOperation_.GetDataFromServer();
    }
}
```

As you see i have a circular dependency here between RestfulNetworkTasks and BaseActivity classes which may cause infinite chain calls of constructors.

The question how can I refactor this design to avoid this?

Comment: Could you format your code somemore? Its kinda unreadable right now. Try copy pasting it into Eclipse and hitting `ctrl-shift-f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AsyncTask will amost always be called from an Activity, so why not just pass it in as a Constructor argument?

RestfulNetworkTasks.java:

```
private BaseActivity activity;

public RestfulNetworkTasks(BaseActivity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

BaseActivity.java:

```
new RestfulNetworkTasks(this).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not create Activity that way

```
BaseActivity instance_Activity = new BaseActivity();
```

Activities are managed by system

Comment: Here is another problem I have! So any solutions how to avoid all this. How to redesign the code?

Comment: @codeman Please read my post attentively and see the real problem I have